# scheme define-syntax body form

Tags: scheme

```
(define-syntax let  
  (syntax-rules ()  
    [(_ ((x e) ...) b1 b2 ...)  
     ((lambda (x ...) b1 b2 ...) e ...)]))
```

> The single rule in our definition of let should be fairly self-explanatory, but a few points are worth mentioning. First, the syntax of let requires that the body contain at least one form; hence, we have specified b1 b2 ... instead of b ..., which might seem more natural.

why use (b1 b2 ...) to represent at lease on form? is that use (b ...) more natural?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`b ...` allows zero or more expressions, whereas for `b1 b2 ...`, `b1` is required to be an expression, while `b2 ...` is zero or more expressions. Since you don't want people writing a bodyless `let`, the `b1 b2 ...` form enforces at least one body expression.

Do you know regular expressions? Think of `b ...` as analogous to `.*`, whereas `b1 b2 ...` is more like `..*`.